# Symfony: How to customize the "none" label appearing on radio field choices?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using radio buttons with **"required" => false**. This makes a "none" option appear along with my other choices.

How can I customize this label (let's say I would want to display "null" instead of "none") ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `placeholder` option to change the label for "None" radio input:

```
->add('color', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array('Red' => 1, 'Blue' => 2, 'Green' => 3),
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'placeholder' => 'Null', // <---- \o/
));
```

Preview:

[image: none-radio-input]

> The placeholder option was introduced in Symfony 2.6 ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder))

Comment: Thanks, now that you say it, it looks so easy!

Comment: @parisssss The placeholder option was introduced in Symfony 2.6 http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder, please check this before a downvote.

Comment: so add it to your answer plz :)

Comment: @parisssss note added, however the answer was totally valid before that symfony3 tag was changed in favor of symfony. Thanks anyway for detect it and recommend you edit the answer instead a downvote for any clarification.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to remove it set `placeholder` to false

```
->add('color', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array('Red' => 1, 'Blue' => 2, 'Green' => 3),
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'placeholder' => false
));
```

Comment: it answers not exactly the question, but useful anyway

Comment: @Michel Funny enough, it was exactly what I was looking for :-)